# How to change the response structure

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am facing one issue to change the following structure.....

THis is the structure I am getting

```
{
    "labels": [
        "List A",
        "List B",
        "List C",
        "List D"
    ],
    "data": [
        19,
        25,
        30,
        32
    ],
    "colors": [
        "#e15759",
        "#f28e2b",
        "#76b7b2",
        "#4e79a7"
    ],
}
```

But I want to change the following data in to the following method

```
    {
        "category": "List D",
        "value": 32,
        "colors":         "#e15759"  
    },
    {
        "category": "List C",
        "value": 25
        "colors": "#f28e2b"
    },
    {
        "category": "List B",
        "value": 30,
        "colors": "#76b7b2"
    },
    {
        "category": "List A",
        "value": 19,
        "colors" : "#4e79a7"

    }
```

Here is my code

```
class AbcListAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        a = data_fuction()
        return Response(a)
```

In this code I am getting this response from a function data_fuction that is used in another part of my code.... So I am unable to edit that response from there ..... But in this function I need to format this code ....

Comment: Can you add ```data_function()```s code in your question?

Comment: Is it possible to edit without making any changes in data_function ?

Comment: how do you match between the values? there is no clear logic...

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359825/4685525 is looks cool. But if you've huge data, for loop runs as slowly. I think you should use serializer as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need function that converts one structure to another

```
data = {
    "labels": [
        "List A",
        "List B",
        "List C",
        "List D"
    ],
    "data": [
        19,
        25,
        30,
        32
    ],
    "colors": [
        "#e15759",
        "#f28e2b",
        "#76b7b2",
        "#4e79a7"
    ],
}

def convert_data(data):
    result = []
    for l, d, c in zip(data['labels'], data['data'], data['colors']):
        result.append({
            'category': l,
            'value': d,
            'colors': c,
        })
    return result


print(convert_data(data))
```